# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) css

Tags: html, css, api

I'm having trouble getting my browser to display the css for the app I am creating. I have looked at the same question asked by other users but have not found any of the answers to help in my situation. When I goto the page, all that is displayed is "Hello world" with no styling even though the stylesheet is linked. When I inspect the page, I get the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

here's the structure of my application

```
.
./public 
     /css
       /main.css
./routes
     /index.js
./views
     /index.html
./server.js
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
const router = require('./routes/index.js');
app.use('/',router);

app.listen(port);

console.log('connected to port: ' + port);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../public/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
 <body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
 </body>
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

router.get('/', function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../views/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `../../public/css/main.css` or `/public/css/main.css`?

Comment: yes, neither work. When doing the first, I get the same error. When trying the second, I get > GET http://localhost:8080/public/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: what's you file tree structure?

Comment: @DaFois refer to the question, I edited it to make structure more noticeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have defined the public dir in app root/public

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

so you have to use:

```
./css/main.css
```

Comment: my failure, dont use public, just ./css

Answer (score 4):

Use the following Code:-

```
../css/main.css
```

**Note: The "../" is shorthand for "The containing directory", or "Up one directory".**

If you don't know the previous folder this will be very helpful..