# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - javaScript CSS files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I've been unable to get css and js to load on my server. MY file structure is as follows:
GAME_Folder
[image]

HTML

```
doctype html
head
  link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap' rel='stylesheet')
  script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript')
  script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/style.css')
  script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

Server (serv.js)

[image]

I've tried almost everything from the previous stack overflow posts: [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317206/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found)
[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517703/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-c/50514909)

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your routing is wrong...

It should be like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/style.css');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/index.js');
```

And in your HTML file:

```
doctype html
head
  link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap' rel='stylesheet')
  script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript')
  script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style.css')
  script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

Comment: I fixed the error by : app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));   So I did not need to change the routing. I have a new error now on my socket.io : jQuery.Deferred exception: io is not defined ReferenceError: io is not defined

Comment: where is your error? Maybe I can help. Or you can create another post and give me the link. :)

Comment: The error was likely due to the fact I had 2 servers, which in my line of thinking, made me assume might work. So what happened was I had to let go of one of my servers as I was unable to merge them.  Thanks anyways, your answer was helpful.